# Calculating server processing time using freeRDP

Tags: amazon-rds, freerdp

I'm connecting to RDS(Remote Desktop Server) using `freeRDP` library.
I want to know how long it takes RDS to process a request.
We will call this **"Server Processing Time"**.
Initially, I was trying to get Server Processing Time by calculating the time difference between when sending a message from a client to RDS using `freeRDP` and when receiving a response sent from RDS after processing that request.

However, I didn't find such a mechanism in `freeRDP` library.
There is `echo` channel, but what I get from this is `Ping Time`, not the "Server Processing Time" I want.

Can I get "Server Processing Time" using `freeRDP` library? Is it possible for me?